# How to choose the underlying statistical model?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, philosophy

Suppose that I have a coin whose output set is $\{+,-\}$. Suppose that the output distribution, $p:(1-p)$, is fixed. Our goal is to guess what $p$ is based on real-world experiments.

Suppose that I have tossed it for $100$ times, and exactly $70$ times were positive $+$ and exactly $30$ times were negative $-$. **How is this experiment supposed to affect my guess about $p$? This is not a math question, but rather a philosophical one.**

Of course, we cannot conclude that $p = 0.7$. All we can say is that under *certain assumptions/requirements* it seems that $ p = 0.7$ is the most reasonable choice, so far.

#### Questions

1. What really are *assumptions/requirements* in the field of statistics? This philosophical choices are often, if not always, omitted or obscured in textbooks, wikipedia, or blog posts.
2. Based on the *assumptions/requirements* given in 1., how does one compare the ($p=0.7$)-model with any other model, say the ($p=0.6$)-model?
3. Maybe one does not want to compare a single model to another, but rather a chunk of models to another chunk. For example, one might wish to compare *that the model has parameter $p \in [0.6,0.8]$* with *that the model has parameter $p \in [0.3,0.5]$*. To do this, it seems to me that we need to integrate some "confidence" function over the intervals $[0.6,0.8]$ and $[0.3,0.5]$. How to define this "confidence" function (essentially reduced to 2.)? And how does one choose the measure on $[0,1]$ for the integrations?

Comment: $0.7$ is the maximum likelihood estimate, the minimum variance unbiased estimate, the mean of the posterior distribution if you start with an improper Haldane prior, and the maximum a posteriori (mode of the posterior distribution) starting with a uniform prior.  Each of these are philosophically different and it would be better to decide your statistical philosophy before trying to make estimates.  Your questions (2) and (3) are about [model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) and again there are many different approaches.

Comment: @Henry That's my guess and thanks for confirming! Can you point out a standard enough account, in which it directly states that one **needs** to make a choice of his/her statistical philosophy before choosing the correct model?